# Query Between date with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I used Mongo 3.2 on debian 8. Node 5.11.1 and Mongoose.
The object are stored

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5756e710eb8863716246689a"
  },
  "id": 735842,
  "employee_id": 477,
  "matricule": "1020510",
  "name": "",
  "date_day": "2016-04-24T22:00:00.000Z",
  "morning_status": "P",
  "morning_time_start": "08:16",
  "morning_time_end": "12:12",
  "afternoon_status": "P",
  "afternoon_time_start": "12:57",
  "afternoon_time_end": "18:30",
  "working_time_theorical": 28800,
  "working_time_employee": 34140,
  "extra_hours": 5340,
  "extra_hours_week": 10680,
  "extra_hours_month": 78120,
  "comments": ""
}
```

I want to extract the data with the field : date_day

```
var reporticoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id :
    {
        type:Number,
        index:true,
        required:true
    },
    employee_id :
    {
        type:Number,
        index:true,
        required:true
    },
    matricule :
    {
        type:String,
        index:true,
        required:true
    },
    date_day :
    {
        type: Date,
        index:true
    },
.....

var Reportico=module.exports = mongoose.model('Reportico',reporticoSchema)

var dateStart=new Date('2016-04-01').toISOString(),
dateEnd=new Date('2016-04-30').toISOString();

console.log('d',dateStart,dateEnd)
var employeeId={employee_id:521,date_day:{$gte:dateStart,$lte:dateEnd}};
//console.log('employeeId',employeeId)
Reportico.find(employeeId).exec(function(err, employees) {
    console.log('result')
    if (err)return console.log('err',err);
    console.log('employees',employees)
})
```

I updated the code to add te format of the field date_day
The result is empty.

Comment: How is the `date_day` field defined in your Mongoose schema, you seem to have skipped this crucial part? Again, if that's defined as the `Date` type then there is no need to parse the JS Date object instance to a string, you can simply use raw JS Date instances in mongo queries without explicitly casting them to `ISOString` format.

Comment: Yes the format of the field is date. Can you more explicit with a sample . Tks.

Comment: If that's the case then all you just need to do is remove the `toISOString()` method on the date instances as that will parse them to strings, which is not necessary here i.e. `var dateStart=new Date('2016-04-01'), dateEnd=new Date('2016-04-30'), query={employee_id:521,date_day:{$gte:dateStart,$lte:dateEnd}};Reportico.find(query).exec(...)`

Comment: I tried too this. In Mongo, i type directly the same query and it have rows. Here the query don't return datas.

Answer (score 1):

This is my consult with date, I using library http://momentjs.com/ to separate date

```
var searchParams = {};
var di = moment('2016-04-01', "YYYY-MM-DD").toArray();
var de = moment('2016-04-30', "YYYY-MM-DD").toArray();
searchParams['date_day'] = { $gte: new Date(di[0],di[1],di[2]), $lte:  new Date(de[0],de[1],de[2]) };
searchParams['employee_id'] = 521

Reportico.find(searchParams).exec(function(err, employees) {
     console.log('result')
     if (err)return console.log('err',err);
     console.log('employees',employees)
})
```

Comment: Hi, the result is the same:
{ date_day: 
   { '$gte': Fri Apr 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST),
     '$lte': Sat Apr 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) },
  employee_id: 521 }
--> employees []
And here the format is : Fri Apr 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) . In Mongo the format is "2016-04-24T22:00:00.000Z"

Comment: Your problem is you need to format the date 

var di = moment(YOUR_DATETIME_START).toArray();
var de = moment(YOUR_DATETIME_END).toArray();