# Finding the Entries between two Entries in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, search

I want to find two different entries in my MongoDB Collection. Then I want to get all the entries that lie between these two.

e.g.

_id: 1
pet: cat

_id: 2
pet: dog

_id : 3
pet: cow

_id: 4
pet: rabbit

_id: 5
pet: crocodile

_id: 6
pet: Pig

Now I want to get all the data between crocodile and dog => I get Dog, Cow, Rabbit, Crocodile.

How does the model.find() function look like?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the _id always numeric? do you know the _id before hand? have you made an attempt?

Comment: @depperm I refer to the default mongodb _ids. So these cannot be used to calculate the difference. I have objects in my collection that have a datetime, which is just a string. I cannot use that to create a query. But the objects in my collection are sorted by datetime. So I want to find two dates in the collection and then get all the values that lie in between

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37686318/3462319